# Multiple App Engine apps inside the same Google Cloud project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have one App Engine app inside a Google Cloud Platform project. How can I create a second App Engine app inside the same project?

I tried to create a new application on https://appengine.google.com/ but it seems to create a new Google Cloud Platform Project.

Answer (score 17):

I believe there is a 1:1 relationship between App Engine **apps** and Cloud projects, but you can create up to 20 (at time of writing) App Engine **services** (previously *modules*) within the same Cloud project.

It depends how much you want the apps / services to be able to share data / task queues, etc.  Services will share the same Datastore, for example.

You can also have multiple Cloud projects associated with the same billing account.